# How to find the termination time of the currently running process in my system?

Tags: python, psutil

I am currently using psutil package , I have used wmi package also but could not find the termination time of running process.

```
import psutil
import datetime

    
for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'username']):
    pro_id = process.info['pid']
    print(process.info)

    p = psutil.Process(pro_id)
    p.create_time()
    print(f'Process Started at : {datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(p.create_time()).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")}')
```

### output

{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 0}
Process Started at : 01-01-1970 05:30:00
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 4}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:26
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 100}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:09
{'username': 'LAPTOP-89SFF6RC\ayush', 'pid': 264}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 16:11:23
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE', 'pid': 356}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:56:00
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 472}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:27
{'username': 'Font Driver Host\UMFD-1', 'pid': 516}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 572}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'Font Driver Host\UMFD-0', 'pid': 600}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 652}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:51
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 768}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 788}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 840}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 848}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 952}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:52
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE', 'pid': 1032}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:53
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE', 'pid': 1068}
Process Started at : 21-12-2022 15:55:53
{'username': 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'pid': 1124}

I need a method which sends a signal at the termination of any running process , using psutil or any other module in python.